# EF4 Computed columns in SQL Server not visible

Tags: entity-framework-4, calculated-columns

I have an SQL server table with one computed column based on 2 other columns on the same table. I have a WCF application in C# that uses EF4 to access the said table.In EF4 the entity corresponding to the said table is missing property(attribute) for the computed column.I tried to refresh the EF Model from the database but to no avail. Is there a limitation in EF where you cannot access a computed column

Comment: I just tried this - works like a charm, that computed column is visible (although: EF generates it like a normal property that could be set to a new value - which of course shouldn't be like that...) Can you try creating a new EDMX model and try again?

Comment: thanks mark I will try again and create a new model. I tried to refresh from database .This process brings in other new columns but not the computed column.

Comment: Filed a bug with Microsoft for this - computed columns must not allow new values to be set from code - doesn't make sense...